# BigQuery Serving Limit Exceeded error

Tags: google-bigquery

even due all my queries run on Batch mode, in the last day i'm getting lot's of error of 
"Serving Limit Exceeded error"

is anyone has a clue why is that if i'm using batch mode?

Comment: I've also run into a lot of these today.

Comment: so what's means? is it quota issue(what's seems to be not) or google temporary issues ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BigQuery API request is stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402971/bigquery-api-request-is-stuck)