# BigQuery API request is stuck

Tags: google-bigquery

In the last 2 days, some of my process are stuck for hours, 
waiting to respond where i'm using.
job = bq_api.jobs().get...
usually it's very fast to get respond.
After killing these process and run again the respond was very fast again,
but it's happen again in the next runs.
for this api i didn't see some timeout params that can be configure in order to deal with these issue.

Comment: I also got a lot of timeout in the last days

Comment: You get timeout or its stuck for hours?

Comment: I get timeouts with the app I am using (Talend). I have no control on the timeout settings and there is no retry mechanism in the tool if the connection timeout. Maybe my problem is not directly related to yours.

Comment: I've noticed this too